# Android XML tableLayout and Gallery problem

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gallery, tablelayout

I wrote this XML code;

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="20" 
>
<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">`enter code here`</TableRow>
<TableRow 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="9">
    <Gallery 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </Gallery>
</TableRow>
<TableRow 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    > 
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button3" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button4" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
</TableRow>
```

This code is shown like I want however when I run the code buttons size are changing with images size in gallery.How can I write the XML code independent from each other(gallery and buttons).
Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use 2 LinearLayouts, A vertical LinearLayout to hold the Gallery and a horizontal LinearLayout, which in turn contains the various buttons.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <Gallery 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Gallery>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button2" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button3" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button4" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tryed your recommend but it looks same.Could you send the code ?